# Android ListView showing images results in out of memory

Tags: android, android-listview

Okay,

I have what I think is an odd problem.

I load photos into a list view *as the user scroll* (meaning if picked up from disk or online, it takes a little time and they "pop in")

1)

I ensure that I only fetch **one image online + resize to 1/3 width** at a time (a lock) -- this is to ensure not e.g. 5 threads each are converting a .jpg to bitmap at the same time. (Imagine a user scrolling very fast, it would then be conceivable this could happen.)

2)

All images on disk are only 1/3 width

3)

While the bitmaps are scaled up to fit device width, I call **recycle** and set bitmaps to null when used in the **getView**. (I am converting bitmaps to a **BitmapDrawable** object which the listitem **imageview** uses in a **setImageDrawable** call)

4)

I reuse view in **getView** if not null

5)

I load bitmaps like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();   
o.inPurgeable = false; // I do not use this since I resize/scale down images myself later
o.inInputShareable = false;
o.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
res.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o);
```

6)

I also clean scrap items

```
public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
          final TextView description = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_news_content);
          description.setText("");
          final ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_news_image);
          image.setImageBitmap(null);                                            
        }
```

I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy II. Do you guys have any ideas on what more I could try? Since I only max need to show 10 items, I would think it should be possible...

Comment: how do you download and decode images? often people run into out of memory exception while decoding images.

Comment: Basicly like this **res.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o);** but I only do max one at a time (and image size may e.g. be JPG 1024*800)

Comment: If it crashes on your S2 after loading 10 images then It could crash on a phone with even low memory even before that. Best way to deal with is use a Library with does loading for you.

Comment: I would like to understand what is going wrong if possible

Answer (score 2):

Try using widely used library Universal Image Loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It is simple and straight forward and you will never have to care about decoding images yourself.

Option two: There's a powerful new API for loading image is available from the team of Square http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I would rather see if I could solve the problem. (I already implemented my own cache-to-disk system and I can also async load images and only load/set them if associated item is still in view.) -- that said, thanks for your links. It is possible I willd have to resort to libraries :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me in case of OutOfMemory...using System.gc()

```
bitmap = null;
imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
System.gc();
```

Comment: You should never force the GC on Android. You should let the system manage it as it is optimized for this.